# when to use show Segues & when to use Show detail Segues

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am new to IOS Development and I am confused between when to use `show segue` & when to use `Show detail segue`. Both them are used in the default master-detail project.

So when do we use either of them? What is the best case to use `show segue` & when to use `show detail segue`?

Comment: The question is simple i am just asking when do we use show Segues & when to use show detail Segues (Adaptive Segues)

Comment: They are the way you navigate from one view to another view or define relationship between one view to another view in IOS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Show segue` can be used with navigation controllers, they simply push viewControllers on your stack.

`Show detail segue` has only sense with split view controllers. Since you have two viewControllers inside your split view controller you can:

- navigate in your master view controller by presenting *(pushing, since the default project uses a navigationVC as master VC)* view controllers with `Show segue`
- show details in your detail view controller with `Show detail segue`

In case you don't know how a Split view controller is composed:

```
**************++++++++++++++++++
*            *                 +
*            *                 +
*   master   *      detail     +
*    view    *       view      +
* controller *    controller   +
*            *                 +
*            *                 +
**************++++++++++++++++++
```

### BUT !

On iphones it's presented like this *(iPhone6+ landscape excluded)*

```
****************
*++++++++++++++*
*+            +*
*+            +*
*+            +*
*+   detail   +*
*+    view    +*
*+ controller +*
*+            +*
*+            +*
*++++++++++++++*
****************
```

Both of `Show segue`and `Show detail segue` are new to iOS8 & Xcode6, they are called adaptative segues, they behaves differently depending on the device type or the orientation.

Basically, `Show segue`and `Show detail segue` seems to do the same thing on iPhones, since there is no much space to present view controllers side by side.

Technically, you don't present details several times until you go back in your navigation. Only the master view controller should perform `Show detail segue`s, a detail view controller should be a leaf in your navigation tree *(but it's not forbidden to use a navigationVC as a leaf* **;)** *)*

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok so cant we use show detail segue in the **non split** layout with size class in use ?

Comment: You can, since it's still a split view controller. It's just collapsed to the needs of the device. Even if it's presented differently, it's semantically the same.